# Marmalade extension and library with c++11 code

Tags: c++11, marmalade

I have a compiled static library for iOS, which uses c++11 functions internally. Can I use this library in extension for Marmalade 8.3 (without c++11 support)? Extension compiles ok on Mac, but when I try to build my app with this extension on PC, I have an error during deploy:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
 __ZNSt3__119__shared_weak_countD2Ev, referenced from:
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ 11 runtime is very different from Cx99 runtime. 
Marmalade 8.4 officialy supports C++ 11.

Try to recompile both the extension and the app with C++ 11 support enabled.

Comment: Thanks, gzito, for your answer. Sadly, Marmalade 8.4 supports C++11, but not for Android/IOS target platforms yet, and I need exactly them.